# When should I use 'al'?

Tags: gramática, contracciones, artículos

I am trying to tell the difference between 'al' and 'a' to refer to a place.

I know that you usually use a to refer to a country. But when should you use al?

I am trying to teach someone the difference but I don't really know how to explain it. I use it all the time as a native speaker, but to explain it is a different story. I tried looking on the internet only to find differences between hay/ahi/ay etc... not really al.

Example:

> Ana y yo vamos a ir al bar.

Why not

> *Ana y yo vamos a ir a bar.
>   (I know this is incorrect. As to why, that is the question)

**EDIT**

As per comments, then can I know when do I need the definite article "el"? Or if there is another explanation for al?

Comment: "al" = "a"+"el", so you just need to know if you need a definite article "el" before the noun or not.

Comment: @Javi Updated :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`al` is basically contraction of `a el`.

`Ir a bar` would be `go to bar`. Which is grammatically incorrect. Correct version is `go to the bar` or `go to a bar`. Thus correct Spanish version is `ir al bar` or `ir a un bar`.

In case of proper names (places, people), you don't usually prepend them with article (there are few exceptions). Thus the correct form is to say `vamos a España`.

Note however, that for example correct way is to say `vamos a El Salvador`, not `vamos al Salvador`.

> Can I know when do I need the definite article "el"?

Always, unless you're using indefinite article or unless there is exception, which says that you shouldn't (eg. proper names).

Answer (score 3):

Because if what's next to the "**ir a**" is a **noun** then that noun must be accompanied by the corresponding **definite article** and the **noun**. You can also use the contraction "**al**" instead of "**a el**" when the **noun is masculine**.

So this could be written as:

> Ana y yo vamos a ir **al** bar.
>
> *Ana y yo vamos a ir **a el** bar.*
>
> **×** *Ana y yo vamos a ir a bar* (No definite article)

When the noun is feminine:

> *Ana y yo vamos a ir a la casa.*
>
> **×** *Ana y yo vamos a ir al casa.* (Incorrect usage casa is feminine noun)

There is an exception to this rule:

- When the noun is a proper name such as a name of a country, city, etc.

> Vamos a ir a México este fin de semana.

If what's next to **"ir a"** acts like a single **verb** (*perífrasis verbal*) then you don't use a definite article neither a contraction.

> *Ana y yo vamos a ir a **jugar**.*

Comment: how about: "ir a Portugal"? "Portugal" is a noun too but doesn't needs "el" before because it's a proper name.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said,

`al` = `a`+`el` in all senses.

However, do not under any circumstances use it in a proper noun, like `El Paso`, where the `artículo definido` is a part of the name.

> (x ) Voy `Al` Paso, Texas.
>
> (✓) Voy `a El` Paso, Texas.

However, some countries require a `artículo definido`, when it is not part of the name.

> Voy a la India.
>
> Voy `al` Brasil.